# Regex on Shell Script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, scripting

I have this regex which works perfectly on my desired matching patterns on https://regex101.com/ (Python).
The problem is that I need to integrate it in a Shell Script which is called from GitBash on Windows 7, but it's not working as expected, compared to when I test it online.

```
pattern='^([a-z][\-a-z0-9_/\.]*)?([A-Z]{3,10}\-[0-9]+([\-a-z0-9_/\.]+)?)?$'
```

usage example:

```
if [[ ! $name =~ $pattern ]]; then ...
```

**Strings to match:**

- abc/this-is/my.test1
- abc/ABC-12345
- ABC-12345
- ABC-12345/test
- ABC-12345/1.0
- aabcd/ABC-123/1.0
- abcd/abc-1234

**Strings to be blocked:**

- abc/THIS-is/my.test1
- 1.0/abc/this-is/my.test1
- Abcd_10/ABCD-12345
- ABCD-12345/ABC-123
- abcd/ABCd-1234
- abc/THISISAVERYLONGEXAMPLE-1234

**My bash version**

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(2)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Your pattern does not work even in Python, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jHl8KQ/1).

Comment: GitBash has access to the stock Unix utilities which are able to filter text using regular expressions: `grep` and `sed` (at least; I'm pretty sure `awk` is available as well). So the answer is to roll like this: 1) stop testing stuff "online"; 2) write a minimal shell script which merely reads its input line-by-line, checks a line matches and prints it, if it does; 3) make two text files—one with the lines which have to match, and another one—with the lines which must not match; 4) verify all lines from the first file pass through your script, and all the lines from the second—do not.

Comment: The basic grep-based filtering loop is something like [this](https://pastebin.com/SThqcvwu).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the observation. It was a typo in the description. I corrected it:  https://regex101.com/r/jHl8KQ/2

Comment: So it is [even worse](https://regex101.com/r/jHl8KQ/3).

Answer (score 1):

It is only a little syntax variation between Python and GNU/Bash.

You just need to change your pattern to that:

```
pattern='^([a-z][-a-z0-9_/\.]*)?([A-Z]{3,10}\-[0-9]+([-a-z0-9_/\.]+)?)?$'
```

At end, I just removed the '\' in front of '-', at the beginning of set, for instance **[-a-z0-9_/.]**, instead of [-a-z0-9_/.]